# mysql: nested if summing

Tags: mysql, if-statement, nested

I want to count how many times confirmed_at was not null given that a promotion_id is either 1483 or 1887.

```
select
    IF(promotion_id IN(1483,1887), sum(IF(confirmed_at IS NOT NULL,1,0)),0) as all_us_vs_voda,
    status_inv
from blabla

group by status_inv
```

Example:

```
promotion_id status_inv confirmed_at
1            'before'    2016-05
1483         'before'    NULL
1483         'after'     2016-05
1483         'after'     2016-07
1887         'before'    2016-08
1887         'before'    2017-09
1887         'after'    2017-09
```

So, the result would be:

```
status_inv  not_nul_specific_promotions
before      2
after       3
```

PS. I want to do it in select statement. I do not want to add "where".

In fact, I was able to do so:

```
sum(IF(promotion_id IN(1483,1887), IF(confirmed_at IS NOT NULL,1,0),0)) as all_us_vs_voda,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `IN` test in the `WHERE` clause so you only count those rows:

```
SELECT status_inv, SUM(IF(confirmed_at IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS not_nul_specific_promotions
FROM blabla
WHERE promotion_id IN (1483, 1887)
GROUP BY status_inv
```

You also don't need the `IF`, since in MySQL booleans evaluate to 1 and 0 for `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

```
SELECT status_inv, SUM(confirmed_at IS NOT NULL) AS not_nul_specific_promotions
FROM blabla
WHERE promotion_id IN (1483, 1887)
GROUP BY status_inv
```

You could also just use `COUNT(confirmed_at)` instead of `SUM()`, because `COUNT()` only counts non-null values.

```
SELECT status_inv, COUNT(confirmed_at) AS not_nul_specific_promotions
FROM blabla
WHERE promotion_id IN (1483, 1887)
GROUP BY status_inv
```

Or put both tests in `WHERE`:

```
SELECT status_inv, COUNT(*) AS not_nul_specific_promotions
FROM blabla
WHERE promotion_id IN (1483, 1887) AND confirmed_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY status_inv
```

If you don't want to use `WHERE`, you can use `AND` in the `IF` test:

```
SELECT status_inv, SUM(IF(confirmed_at IS NOT NULL AND promotion_id IN (1483, 1887), 1, 0) AS not_nul_specific_promotions
FROM blabla
GROUP BY status_inv
```

Comment: I've added another version to the answer, but I don't understand why you can't use `WHERE`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count` for this, here is the query:

```
select STATUS_INV,count(case when PROMOTION_ID=1483  THEN 1 when PROMOTION_ID =1887 THEN 1  ELSE NULL END) 
as confirmed_at FROM sample WHERE confirmed_at IS NOT NULL  group by STATUS_INV
```